# Gear defect detection with image processing

Tags: image, algorithm, opencv, image-processing

My input will be the gear detect file. I am trying figure out what kind of a binary image
processing pipeline I should set up in order to detect the defects of these gears. An
output example is also provided (Ouput of result). How to detect gear with using image processing techniques. I am studying image processing (opening,dilation,closing,erosion,addition,    subtraction etc. which linear operations.) Thank for help.

[image: Output of Result]
[image: Gear detect]

Comment: any reason why your images are of such low quality? how do you acquire them?

Comment: I need to process the gear image. I mean , I will do some operation which are dilation, erosion , openning , union or etc. in order to find detect gear that output of result image. I don't need a code just what will be processed operations?

Comment: but why do you have such bad images? what does your input image look like?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean. We don't care bad images or good image. We need to find detect gear with some operations.